# Pagination in view does not show last entry on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have this problem:
the links form codeigniter pagination class does not show last entry,

e.g. if the total number of rows returned is 2, it will display on one results and the links to the last entry would be greyed out.

**Here is the Controller:**

```
function productlisting () {

  $ids=$this->uri->segment(3);
  $this->load->library('pagination');
  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/listing_category/productlisting/'.$ids;
  $config['per_page'] = '1';

  $this->load->model('product_model');

  $config['total_rows'] =$this->load->model('product_model')->get_num_product();

  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
 //load the model and get results
  $pages = $this->uri->segment(3);//? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
                                                                                                $query['products']=$this->load->model('product_model')->get_specific_product($config['per_page'],$pages);
    $query['paginated']=$this->pagination->create_links();
       // load the view

echo $config['base_url'].'<br/>';
echo 'total rows:'. $config['total_rows']; 

$this->template->build('product_display',$query);

}
```

**Here is my model**

```
//query to get the total number of rows

function get_num_product(){

   $listingcategory = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $this->db->select('default_listings.listing_id_unique,manufacturer,imagename,item_location,thumbnail,default_listings.item_category_id,product_name,item_serial_number,item_description,size,accessories,othercharacteristics,product_age');

$this->db->where('default_listings.item_category_id',$listingcategory);
$this->db->from('default_listings');

$this->db->join('default_listings_pics', 'default_listings.listing_id_unique=default_listings_pics.listing_id_unique', 'left');

$this->db->distinct('listing_id_unique');
$this->db->group_by('default_listings.listing_id_unique');

$queried= $this->db->get();

$rowcount = $queried->num_rows();
return $rowcount;
}



// Query to get the actual entries
function get_specific_product($num, $offset){

  $listingcategory = $this->uri->segment(3);
  $this->db->select('default_listings.listing_id_unique,manufacturer,imagename,item_location,thumbnail,default_listings.item_category_id,product_name,item_serial_number,item_description,size,accessories,othercharacteristics,product_age');

  $this->db->where('default_listings.item_category_id',$listingcategory);
  $this->db->from('default_listings');
  $this->db->join('default_listings_pics', 'default_listings.listing_id_unique=default_listings_pics.listing_id_unique', 'left');
  $this->db->distinct('listing_id_unique');
  $this->db->group_by('default_listings.listing_id_unique');
  $this->db->limit($num, $offset);
  $query= $this->db->get()->result();

  return $query;

  }
```

**and finally my view**

```
 <div id="catetogorylisitngcover">
      <h1>Products</h1>
    <?php foreach ( $products as  $productdetail):?>

      <div class="eachproducts">

      <div class="productimage">
         <?php if($productdetail->thumbnail):?>
              <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>pictures/<?php echo $productdetail->thumbnail;?>"/>
        <?php else :?>
          <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/noimage.png"/>
```

```
     </div>
    <div class="productcover">
     <div><span >Category Id:</span><span class="producttext"><?php  echo  $productdetail->item_category_id ;?></span></div>

  <div><span >Product Name:</span><span class="producttext"><?php  echo $productdetail->product_name;?></pan></div>  

   <div><span >Manufacturer :</span><span class="producttext"><?php  echo  $productdetail->manufacturer;?></span></div>

   <div><span >Location :</span><span class="producttext"><?php  echo  $productdetail->item_location;?></span></div>
    <div><span >Listing Id :</span><span class="producttext"><?php  echo  $productdetail->listing_id_unique;?></span></div>
 <div class="learmoreproduct"><a href="lister/specificDetails/<?php  echo intval($productdetail->listing_id_unique);?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/prodreadmore.png"/></a></div>  

  </div>

 </div>

<?php endforeach;?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>
```

Help needed!

Answer (score 0):

use it as

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = your base url without offset in your case // base_url().'index.php/listing_category/productlisting/';
$config['total_rows'] = your total number of rows;
$config['per_page'] = number of rows you want to display;
$config['uri_segment'] = uri segment which will be used as offset;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```